# What is the difference between Gson.fromJson which takes class as parameter and the one that takes Type as parameter?

Tags: java, json, gson

I was trying to parse a Json object with a structure as follows:

```
{
"something@email.com": {
    "data1": {
        "fullName": "Mr X Y",
        "givenName": "X"
    },
    "data2": {
        "age": "70",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    "data3": [
        {
            "typeId": "xyz",
            "url": "xyz.com"
        }
    ],
    "status": 200,
},
"anotherThing@email.com": {
    "data1": {
        "fullName": "Mr A B",
        "givenName": "A"
    },
    "data2": {
        "age": "20",
        "gender": "Male"
    },
    "data3": [
        {
            "typeId": "abc",
            "url": "abc.com"
        }
    ],
    "status": 200,
}
}
```

I created a bean `TempBean` with a field `Map<String, Person>`, with `Person` as another bean appropriately defined to accept the Json.

I tried:

```
Gson.fromJson(data, TempBean.class)
```

but couldn't parse. Also tried `Map.class` and accepted a `Map<String, Person>`, but couldn't parse.

However, when I used:

```
Type dataType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Person>>() {}.getType();
```

and then,

```
Map<String, Person> tempMap = Gson.fromJson(data, dataType);
```

I could parse it..!

I wish to know what was the difference it the two approaches and what more should I know to be clear about all of this.

Comment: I apologise for a long and badly formed query..!! I could've said this in a simpler way..

Comment: Look up "reifiable types" in Java.

Comment: You can't get the compile time type checking with `Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's official explanation is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Generic-Types).